# Set PDFView destination

Tags: swift, pdfview

I'm trying to set a PDFView to a specified destination with some code below.

But after I set it, the PDFView destination is not the same like what I saved before.

```swift
@IBOutlet var pdfView: PDFView!

func saveDirection() {
    previousDestination = pdfView.currentDestination!
}

func setDirection() {
    pdfView.go(to: previousDestination)
}
```

Are there any mistakes in my code?